# len function show last 5 character in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I like the last 5 Digit results show the len function in Google Sheets like

[image]
Thank you for your time.

Comment: the `RIGHT` function will get you the last 'n' characters.

Comment: If your first value is in A1, then =right(A1,5) will return result F0001

Comment: Thank you it was simple but I don't know thanks  
@user11222393
as well  Matthew

Comment: I recommend that you post your comment as an answer to this post @user11222393

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the values is in Column A. Using `RIGHT` function:

```
=right(A1,5) // result F0001
=right(A2,5) // result F0003
=right(A2,5) // result FD007
```

Reference: [RIGHT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094087)